# How to pass env-var to MSBuild Task and make it effective for all sub-process? (concrete code)

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a question about passing environment variables to `MSBuild` Task. See my code below:

a.proj

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" 
    DefaultTargets="A1">
    
    <Target Name="A0">
        <Message Text="A0 start."/>
        <MSBuild Projects="b.proj" Properties="myvar=000" />
        <Message Text="A0 end."/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="A1" DependsOnTargets="A0">
        <Message Text="A1 start."/>
        <MSBuild Projects="b.proj" Properties="myvar=111" />
        <Message Text="A1 end."/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

b.proj

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="B">
        <Message Text="B start."/>
        <Exec command="c.bat" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

c.bat

```
echo [C]myvar=%myvar%
```

I hope that `c.bat` can see `myvar`'s value passed from `a.proj`. My code above failed to do that.

[image]

Consider(Assume) a running <MSBuild> Task a process on the OS, then, I'd like to pre-set environment variable `myvar` for that process, so that its subprocesses(no matter how deep) can all see `myvar`'s value.

How can I achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: The batch file is trying to write an environment variable named 'myvar'. You can verify this by settings the 'myvar' in the environment before invoking `msbuild` and you'll see that value printed twice. MSBuild properties are not the same as environment variables. You would need a target to set environment variables before invoking the bat script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MSBuild starts, it maps the environment variables in its process to MSBuild Properties. For example the environment variable `COMPUTERNAME` is available in an MSBuild project as the `$(COMPUTERNAME)` property.

But Properties are not added to the environment variables.

The [`Exec` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2022) creates a new process. The new process will inherit the environment variables of the 'parent' process and `Exec` has a parameter for passing additional environment variable definitions that will either add to or override the existing environment variables. The parameter is `EnvironmentVariables`.

Modify your `Exec` task as follows:

```
        <Exec command="c.bat" EnvironmentVariables="myvar=$(myvar)" />
```

### Example

The following is a full example of the environment variable passing.

Given a file 'test.proj':

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="TestExecPassVar">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFile)" Targets="ExecPassVar" Properties="myvar=000" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFile)" Targets="ExecPassVar" Properties="myvar=111" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFile)" Targets="ExecPassVar" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="ExecPassVar">
    <Exec Command="test.bat" EnvironmentVariables="myvar=$(myvar)" EchoOff="true" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

And given a file 'test.bat':

```
@echo running test.bat
@echo %myvar%
```

Running the command

```
set myvar=222
```

and then

```
msbuild test.proj
```

will produce output like the following (which has been edited to remove paths and other noise):

```
Project "test.proj" on node 1 (TestExecPassVar target(s)).
Project "test.proj" (1) is building "test.proj" (1:2) on node 1 (ExecPassVar target(s)).
ExecPassVar:
  running test.bat
  000
Done Building Project "test.proj" (ExecPassVar target(s)).

Project "test.proj" (1) is building "test.proj" (1:3) on node 1 (ExecPassVar target(s)).
ExecPassVar:
  running test.bat
  111
Done Building Project "test.proj" (ExecPassVar target(s)).

Project "test.proj" (1) is building "test.proj" (1:4) on node 1 (ExecPassVar target(s)).
ExecPassVar:
  running test.bat
  222
Done Building Project "test.proj" (ExecPassVar target(s)).

Done Building Project "test.proj" (TestExecPassVar target(s)).
```

The test project invokes its own `ExecPassVar` target three times. The first two times it passes `Properties` that define a `$(myvar)` property. The third time no property is passed and the `$(myvar)` property is undefined.

The `Exec` task uses the `EnvironmentVariables` parameter.

When the `$(myvar)` property is defined, the batch file sees a `myvar` environment variable with the passed value.

When the `$(myvar)` property is not defined, the `EnvironmentVariables` parameter value evaluates to `"myvar="`. This doesn't override or clear the value of `myvar` and the value of `222`, that was set before the msbuild command, is seen by the batch file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `<Exec EnvironmentVariables=...>`, it's a big step forward. However, it's still not perfect, bcz `<Exec>` have to explicitly **relay** all env-var definitions from `Properties=...`, a sign of code duplication.

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly set all the environment variables that you want defined from property values. There can be hundreds of properties in an MSBuild run and mapping all properties to the environment would not be helpful. You can use a Property or ItemGroup to create and re-use the set of environment variables that need to be passed.